# How to make string respect line breaks <br />

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have the following data coming from a mysql DB in laravel.

```
"hi this is my text I appear this way in the database
 • I have some points
 • Like so
 • And another"
```

I wish to display the data this way in a for each loop that pulls the string and displays it.
To achieve this I tried:

```
<p class="details-description">{{ str_replace("•", "<br /> •", $d->description) }}</p>
```

My logic being that I would replace the • with a break before each item.  However in the rendered html it displays like so:

```
"hi this is my text I appear this way in the database
 <br /> • I have some points
 <br /> • Like so
 <br /> • And another"
```

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php) and use raw filter (if this is blade) with `{!!` syntax

```
<p> {!! nl2br($d->description) !!} </p>
```